# OpenSSL hash of a file is the same in C

Tags: c, file, hash, openssl, cryptography

am learning to do the hash of a file in C using OpenSSL but I always get the same hash. I have tried different files and content but the hash do not change. If i use different files it should show different hash.I am not sure where the problem is.

This is my code:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int fd;
   char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
   int i = 0;

   SHA_CTX sha_ctx;
   unsigned char sha_hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

   SHA1_Init(&sha_ctx);

   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0);
   do {
      i = read(fd, buff, i);
      SHA1_Update(&sha_ctx, buff, i);
   } while(i > 0);
   close(fd);

   SHA1_Final(sha_hash, &sha_ctx);

   printf("\n Hash of the file: %s \n\n", argv[1]);
   for(i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
      printf("%x", sha_hash[i]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Compile like this

```
gcc -g hash.c -lcrypto
```

Comment: In the code you posted, you are not checking the return values of the function calls `open` and `read` for failure. Did you ever check whether these functions are failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

```
i = read(fd, buff, i);
```

`i` is initialized to zero, so you're telling `read()` to read at most 0 characters. Instead, you should specify your buffer size:

```
i = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
```

I also recommend you add error checks to `open` and `read` calls, as the comment by Andreas Wenzel suggests. Check your `argc` to make sure you got the number of command line arguments expected as well.